# loading .mat file into python causing 'buffer is too small for requested array' error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, encode

I have the following python code (its dummy data)

```
import scipy.io as si
data = [0 ,1]
metadata = {'Location_City': {'loíza': '0'}}
metadata_b = bytes(str(metadata), 'utf-8') 
result_dict = {'d':data, 'm': metadata_b}
si.savemat('data.mat', mdict = result_dict)
```

Notice the i with an accent in loíza. When I load the file into python, I get an error 'buffer is too small for requested array':

```
res = loadmat('data.mat', uint16_codec='utf-8')
```

I know the error is due to encoding the metadata with special characters. I am using uint16_codec='utf-8' in loadmat() but that did not help. I want to save the metadata in the .mat file. Metadata contains dictionary of dictionaries with names having special characters. I also want to load .mat file in python with that metadata. Any suggestions?

Comment: `octave` load also has problems with this UTF8 character(s).

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4431 - using UTF-16 avoids the immediate problem, but I can't decode the loaded string.

Comment: Simply saving the unicode works for save/load, `str(metadata)`.  I can't load that in Octave either.  Or save `json.dumps(metadata)`